# javascript: opening uri with telephone or email wont work on ios devices

Tags: javascript, ios

I am trying this:

```
window.location.assign("tel:"+telephone, "_self");
```

This works on all browser and all platforms, except (of course) on iPhone, where the page just reloads itself.

The same issue happens on opening the email application. Works everywhere (even on mac) just never on iPhone.

What could be of issuehere?

Comment: What browser is your iPhone using?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Do you try ```window.location.href = "tel:"+telephone;```?

Comment: i tried both on different iphones with sarafi, i get no error msg. i also tried window.location.href this .